# How do I change characters at the Hideout?

Tags: bomb-rush-cyberfunk

Is there a way to switch characters while in the Hideout? I am trying to cover the hideout with unique graffiti pieces for the *State of the Art* achievement and would like to avoid having to leave the area every time I want to change characters.

Most areas have a checkerboard floor you can dance on to change characters, but I can't find one in the Hideout. Mesh gives me an option to play as him if I talk to him, but I don't get that option when talking to other characters like Tryce, Vinyl, or Solace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A patch released August 30, 2023](https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/1353230/view/3646281279369270483) added a cypher spot to the Hideout for changing characters.

[image: cypher spot in hideout]